# Receiver for device media buttons NOT "media button"

Tags: android, media-player, broadcastreceiver

My goal is to start a service with a media button event received from another application (i.e., when to user selects play/pause in a given media app). The catch is, I need to target the media buttons on their device and **not on their headset.**

**To clarify** I am aware of the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON and am almost certain it is of no value for my purpose. I may be wrong though. But I'm pretty sure.

**I need** an approach that targets the media buttons of the device itself.

I'm completely lost and sleep deprived. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The catch is, I need to target the media buttons on their device and not on their headset.

There are no hardware media buttons on their device, for hundreds of millions of devices, beyond perhaps volume buttons. If you are dealing with some specific device that has other hardware media buttons, you will need to contact the device's manufacturer for details.

If, by "media buttons" and "when to user selects play/pause in a given media app", you are trying to spy on other applications, this is not possible, for obvious privacy reasons. Some media players have an API for announcing track changes and the like, which you might be able to use, but there is no standard API that I am aware of, and neither the AOSP Music app nor Google's proprietary Play Music app have any such documented and supported API.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks for clarifying a few concepts I didn't fully understand and congrats for being able to decifer what I meant to say. One last thing if I may:

Comment: @Steve: Um, well, maybe you may, but your comment appears to have been chopped off.

Comment: I'm clearly not a programmer. I'm a medical research post-grad investigating mp3 players and hearing loss. Point being, when I contact Google is there any way they could allow this restriction to be bypassed? Or is it inherently prohibited by the system? (that is, did they put a road block up or is there no road at all?) Thanks a lot

Comment: @Steve: "when I contact Google" -- you have a better chance of getting an audience with the Pope. "is there any way they could allow this restriction to be bypassed?" -- they will tell you to learn OS engineering and modify the firmware, putting that firmware on your own devices. "Or is it inherently prohibited by the system?" -- it is inherently prohibited by the system, as it is on any sensible OS. Now, you *could* try to use the accessibility APIs to address this, the way screenreaders for the blind do, but I don't know how you will distinguish "selects play/pause in a given media app".

Comment: @Steve: "I'm a medical research post-grad" -- I suspect that you will have better luck getting answers to your questions via a conversation, rather than by posting questions here. See if your university offers Android courses and try to contact the instructor. Or, see if there is some other way of identifying Android app developers who might be students or faculty at your university.

Comment: "screenreaders for the blind" is a great idea. I'll look into that. Chances are I'll probably have to use the HEADSET_PLUG event I just found to start the activity and modify my methodology. Thanks a lot though.